# why is the text appearing above an image with a high z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

if you pass your mouse over the image on this jsfiddle, it does not overlap the text around it.

pretty dumb question, but i am very confused, could someone help me?

http://jsfiddle.net/wdhf2/

the image has this css:

```
.img {
    height:30px;
    -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
    transition-duration:0.5s;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-right:0px;
    z-index:100000000;
}
.img:hover {
    height:300px;
    margin-bottom:-270px;
    margin-right:-270px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` can be applied only to positioned elements.  Here's a fiddle with an image covering all the text after it has been positioned absolutely: http://jsfiddle.net/hb8f2/.  Using `position: relative` or `position: fixed` also allows application of `z-index`.

```
.img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: minimal change huge effect! Effective!